The Fourier Transform of Inhomogeneous Riesz Kernel
It is known that the Fourier transform of Riesz kernel $I_{\alpha}(x)=|x|^{-(n-\alpha)}$ for $0<\alpha<n$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is $|\xi|^{\alpha}$ in the distributional sense. I am looking for the reference of the Fourier transform of inhomogeneous Riesz kernel $I_{\alpha,\rho}(x)=|x|^{-(n-\alpha)}\chi_{|x|<\rho}$. I believe it is computed somewhere in the literature, but I couldn't find one.
